# How to check if a particular thread is finished execution in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want a function which takes thread name and returns if it is running or not. I have tried isAlive function of java but it did not work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used ctx.getThread().getEndTime() . This function i have used to get thendtime of current thread in JSR223 Post processor but got zero as answer.

Comment: import java.lang.Object;
var endTime =ctx.getThread().getEndTime(); 
log.info("EndTime is:"+endTime);

Answer (score 0):

As an exception I can give you a hint: if you look into [ThreadGroup class source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.java#L77) you will see something like:

```
// List of active threads
private final ConcurrentHashMap<JMeterThread, Thread> allThreads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

So all active threads live in `allThreads` map of the ThreadGroup.

Knowing this you can attempt to [find](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)) the thread by name in this map, if it is not null - the thread is running and vice versa.

Example code:

```
def threadName = 'Thread Group 1-1'

def threadGroup = ctx.getThreadGroup()
def field = org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.getDeclaredField(threadGroup.getClass(), 'allThreads', true)
def allThreads = field.get(threadGroup)

def thread1 = allThreads.keySet().find { key -> key.getThreadName().equals(threadName) }

if (thread1 != null) {
    log.info('Thread ' + threadName + ' is running')
} else {
    log.info('Thread ' + threadName + ' is not running')
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)